# sed on OS X - can't seem to use + in regexps

Tags: regex, macos, sed

Now according to all the literature

```
echo 1234abcd|sed "s|[0-9]\+|#|g"
```

should output #abcd. And

```
echo abcd|sed "s|[0-9]\+|#|g"
```

should output abcd.

But on OS X 10.4.11 the first expression outputs 1234abcd. Using * instead of + works for the first example but fails on the second, outputting #abcd, because the [0-9] pattern is matched zero times.

Does the + operator not work in regular expressions in OS X? Is there an alternative?

Thanks

Comment: sed does not 'return abcd'.  It returns 0, and it outputs "abcd".  The output of a program is *not* its return value.

Comment: You are very correct sir. I fixy-fix now.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

On OSX, `sed` by default uses basic REs. You should use `sed -E` if you want to use modern REs, including the `"+"` one-or-more operator.

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/sed.1.html) for the indication that `sed` uses basic REs by default, [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man7/re_format.7.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/7/re_format) for the modern RE syntax, and [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ed.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/ed) for the basic RE (`ed`) information.

---

Alternatively, if you have a regular expression engine that *doesn't* support `+` at all, you can simply use `*` instead, by converting (for example):

```
[a-z]+
```

into:

```
[a-z][a-z]*
```

Comment: This answer is technically correct, however I have been continually frustrated by the -E flag because it is not portable to any of the versions of sed which are commonly included in Linux distributions.  Caveat Emptor.

Comment: @JayTaylor I just came here because my regex didn't work properly on Ubuntu Lucid and specifying `-E` solved the problem.

Comment: @AndreKR The `-E` flag will work anytime you're using that extended dialect of regex.  I wish I could help more and without additional details there's not much else I can say!

Comment: @JayTaylor I thought you were saying that on Linux the `-E` flag doesn't work. I found that it not only works on Linux, it's even necessary if you want to use quantifiers.

Comment: Now I understand the point of confusion; yes! the `-E` flag is portable between Mac and POSIX-compliant Linux versions `sed`.  Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

Obsolete basic regular expressions do not support `+` and `?` quantifiers. They are regular characters.

Alternatives for `[0-9]+` are e.g. `[0-9]{1,}` or `[0-9][0-9]*`.

Or you can use `sed -E` to use modern, extended regular expressions.

Comment: It seems like `-E` still does not give you truly "modern" regular expressions because it's still missing support for other standard things like `\d`

Answer (score 2):

If + doesn't work, you can always use {1,}

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk

```
# echo 1234abcd| awk '{gsub(/[0-9]+/,"#")}1'
#abcd

# echo abcd| awk '{gsub(/[0-9]+/,"#")}1'
abcd
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to learn awk next. I'm still getting my head around sed though.

Comment: not going to stop you from learning sed, but once you know awk in and out, there is no need to use sed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the OS X unix utilities are of versions that lack the comforts of their GNU equivalents. As Pax says, you can use -E:

```
drigz@mbp drigz 0$ echo 1234abcd | /usr/bin/sed "s/[0-9]\+/#/g" 
1234abcd
drigz@mbp drigz 0$ echo 1234abcd | /usr/bin/sed -E "s/[0-9]+/#/g" 
#abcd
```

Note that small changes to the syntax of your regex are required (\+ to + in this case).

However, I prefer to use fink to get GNU utilities:

```
drigz@mbp drigz 0$ echo 1234abcd | /sw/bin/sed "s/[0-9]\+/#/g"
#abcd
drigz@mbp drigz 0$ /sw/bin/sed --version
GNU sed version 4.1.5
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you meant \\+ to + (the formatting seems to have eaten the escape character)

Unfortunately the firewall in this place seems to block fink, and macports, so there's a whole lot og GNU fun I can't access.

Comment: hmm.. sometimes it eats the \ sometimes not

Comment: Yes - you're right. Could you install them the old way? (./configure && make && sudo make install)

Comment: Good idea. I'll go look for the source.

Comment: Since I posted my last comment I've discovered Hombrew, so no need for compiling or indeed using fink or macports: http://brew.sh