# sed 's/\s+$//g' does not strip trailing space

Tags: sed

I expected `sed 's/\s+$//g'` to strip trailing spaces

```
echo "'$(echo 'Magnetic ' | sed 's/\s+$//g')'"
```

outputs `'Magnetic '`, as does

```
echo "'$(echo 'Magnetic ' | sed 's/[\n\s]+$//g')'"
```

How do I remove the trailing space with `sed`?

Comment: `sed -E 's/\s+$//g'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sed's "+" quantifier does not seem to match anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38721274/seds-quantifier-does-not-seem-to-match-anything) Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426457/plus-quantifier-not-working-as-expected-using-regex-for-substitution-in-sed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227174/sed-on-os-x-cant-seem-to-use-in-regexps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the plus sign `+` because sed uses BRE, so:

```bash
echo "'$(echo 'Magnetic ' | sed 's/\s\+$//g')'"
```

if there's `-r` or `-E` flag, sed uses ERE instead so you don't have to escape it:

```bash
echo "'$(echo 'Magnetic ' | sed -r 's/\s+$//g')'"
```